# cannot add certbot ppa ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, certbot

I am having problem adding certbot ppa. Here is the log.

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp4pghptu5/pubring.gpg' created gpg: 
/tmp/tmp4pghptu5/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created gpg: key 8C47BE8E75BCA694: public key "Launchpad PPA for certbot" imported gpg: 
Total number processed: 1 gpg: imported: 1 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func func(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
```

Here is my apt-get update log:

```
root@c931b6739389:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease [63.0 kB]
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                           
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                             
Get:6 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [458 kB]  
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic Release
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic Release
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic Release
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main md64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages   
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages     
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages   
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages     
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic/main 
all Packages
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic/main all 
Packages
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu 
bionic/main all Packages
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
Fetched 521 kB in 22s (23.4 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Can you improve the format?

Comment: If there is a problem while installing any program, you should file a bug report. I don't see any connection to programming here

Comment: Well I was trying to install certbot in the nginx docker container which is might not be possible, so now I have added certbot's docker image, and it works now. @NicoHaase I didnt files the report because I know its not the issue of certbot but of my system, I am new on docker, never worked before so having tuff time understanding and implementing it.

Comment: I have the same issue with vagrant+virtualbox.